# rxjs check outerobservable is not null and only then subscribe to inner observeable

Tags: rxjs

I want to subscribe to inner observable only when the outer observable is not null.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, delay, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

//emit delay value
const source = of(2000, 1000);

// map value from source into inner observable, when complete emit result and move to next
const example = source.pipe(
  concatMap(val => of(`Delayed by: ${val}ms`).pipe(delay(val)))
);

//output: With concatMap: Delayed by: 2000ms, With concatMap: Delayed by: 1000ms
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val =>
  console.log(`With concatMap: ${val}`)
);
```

How do i check if the `val` parameter passed to `concatMap` is not null ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain the observable pipeline with the RxJS [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter) operator, such only values that aren't null will be emitted, and be passed onto the subsequent `concatMap()`.

```
const example = source.pipe(
  filter(val => val !== null),
  concatMap(val => of(`Delayed by: ${val}ms`).pipe(delay(val)))
);
```